# Getting a few errors about Material-Table in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, material-table

My code is that. I hid the titles, fields, and API due to company issues.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table'


function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const columns = [
    { title: "x", field: "x" },
    { title: "x", field: "x" },
    { title: "x", field: "x" },
    { title: "x", field: "x" },
    { title: "x", field: "x" },
    { title: "x", field: 'x' },
    { title: "x", field: 'x' },
    { title: "x", field: 'x' },
  ]
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("API_URL")
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(resp => {
        setData(resp)
      }) 
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 align="center">x</h1>
      <h4 align='center'>x</h4>
      <MaterialTable
        title="Table View"
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So, here are the errors I am getting.

1.

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onChangePage` of `ForwardRef(TablePagination)` is deprecated. Use the `onPageChange` prop instead.
TablePagination@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30964:31
WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
tr
TableRow@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:31415:17
WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
tfoot
TableFooter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30681:17
WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
table
Table@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30026:17
WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
div
Paper@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:22045:17
WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
Container
Provider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:129435:15
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93693:19
ErrorBoundary@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:86893:35
DragDropContext@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93825:19
MaterialTable@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78672:34
./node_modules/material-table/dist/index.js/_default<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78556:5
WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
div
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:170:82
```

2. Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onChangeRowsPerPage` of `ForwardRef(TablePagination)` is deprecated. Use the `onRowsPerPageChange` prop instead.
   TablePagination@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30964:31
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   tr
   TableRow@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:31415:17
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   tfoot
   TableFooter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30681:17
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   table
   Table@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30026:17
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   div
   Paper@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:22045:17
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   Container
   Provider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:129435:15
   App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93693:19
   ErrorBoundary@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:86893:35
   DragDropContext@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93825:19
   MaterialTable@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78672:34
   ./node_modules/material-table/dist/index.js/_default<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78556:5
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   div
   App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:170:82
3. Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onPageChange` is marked as required in `ForwardRef(TablePagination)`, but its value is `undefined`.
   TablePagination@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30964:31
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   tr
   TableRow@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:31415:17
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   tfoot
   TableFooter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30681:17
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   table
   Table@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:30026:17
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   div
   Paper@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:22045:17
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   Container
   Provider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:129435:15
   App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93693:19
   ErrorBoundary@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:86893:35
   DragDropContext@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93825:19
   MaterialTable@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78672:34
   ./node_modules/material-table/dist/index.js/_default<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78556:5
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   div
   App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:170:82
4. Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `data` supplied to `MaterialTable`.
   MaterialTable@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78672:34
   ./node_modules/material-table/dist/index.js/_default<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:78556:5
   WithStyles@http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42982:25
   div
   App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:170:82

Comment: It says clearly what the problem is. *Failed prop type: The prop onChangeRowsPerPage of ForwardRef(TablePagination) is deprecated. Use the onRowsPerPageChange prop instead.*

Comment: I didn't use that props only, that's the problem.

Comment: I think the library you are using are not up-to-date somehow. Why not use components from material UI themselves instead of some random people trying to do the same thing? https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

Comment: First three errors are okay actually. But because of 4th error, I cannot see the datas on table. It doesn't show any data.